# How to install nodejs 8.x version on centos 6? 1

Tags: node.js, centos

```
[root@~]# sudo n stable
install : node-v9.0.0
mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/9.0.0
fetch : https://nodejs.org/dist/v9.0.0/node-v9.0.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
    ######################################################################## 100.0%
installed : v6.11.5
```

the install version and installed version different. run node -v still got v6.11, cant update nodejs, whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Version 6 probably appears in your $PATH before v9. The node binary that it first finds will be the one used.

Also, there might be a node sym-link that points to the wrong version. Use `which node` to see where the bin is.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using nvm for managing Node versions https://github.com/creationix/nvm
It makes it simpler